# Credit card payment without address line 1, city, and state?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to process a credit card transaction without using the line 1, city, and state values in the credit_card.billing_address object?

```
"funding_instruments": [
  {
    "credit_card": {
      "type": "visa",
      "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx0331",
      "expire_month": "11",
      "expire_year": "2018",
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Shopper",
      "billing_address": {
        "line1": "52 N Main ST",
        "city": "Johnstown",
        "state": "OH",
        "postal_code": "43210",
        "country_code": "US"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API seems to require the billing address.  If you use the Payments Pro / PayFlow API, though, you can adjust the AVS and CVV2 settings in your Fraud Filters so you could then process credit cards without an address.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  Where would I find the fraud filters?